# separate email server for the subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, mx-record, dns-zone

I am having some serious problems setting up the proper DNS addresses for my domain.

My DNS records are like

```
mail              A         ip1 (shared hosting provider)
mail              A         ip2 (VPS mail server)
info              A         ip2
mail.info         CNAME     domain.com
info.domain.com   MX    5   mail.info
```

Now, from server 2. I am able to send emails but when someone replies to the email then I am not receiving the email. there might be some issues in these above DNS records. can someone please help me figure it out?

Comment: You're going to want to start by looking to your mail server logs for more information on the problems.

Comment: Please don't use `domain.com` but `example.com` when you obfuscate things. Better: do not obfuscate and give real names which will prompt far better answers.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've set that up translates to the following:

A server that tries to send email to `somebody@info.domain.com` opens a connection to `mail.info`, which in itself is a CNAME for `domain.com`.

If you want Server2 (which I assume has the IP `ip2`) to receive email sent to `somebody@info.domain.com`, you'll need to change that record to point to `mail.domain.com`

But you also have 2 records for `mail.domain.com`, which means that the DNS server will round-robin load balance between those records, so incoming mail will randomly be sent to either `ip1` or `ip2`, which is probably not what you want.

Here's how you'd usually set this up:

```
mail              A         1.2.3.4 (mail server)
domain.com.       MX    5   mail.domain.com
```

Do note that if you add multiple MX records for a domain, it's assumed that any of those servers are responsible for any mail sent to that domain. And any particular email is only sent to a single mail server, not to every mail server listed in DNS.

EDIT:

Here's how I would configure it based on the comments below:

```
mail1             A         ip1 (shared hosting provider)
mail2             A         ip2 (VPS mail server)
info              A         ip2
domain.com        MX    5   mail1
info.domain.com   MX    5   mail2
```

Comment: I want it like if someone send an email to somebody@domain.com then it must be handled by ip1. And if someone send an email to somebody@info.domain.com then it must be handled by ip2. How can I set it up that way ?

Comment: still, I am unable to receive email on somebody@info.domain.com.I have updated the dns addresses as you have told. I am using virtualmin on linux. I am unable to figure out what is the real problem.